# No type or until time on my US visa stamp

Tags: visas, usa

I am a Canadian filling out an US visa form. They ask for all previous US visas, except those for tourism. I have a few US stamps which have neither the visa type (B1/B2 etc) nor the until date. Where can I find them please?

Comment: [Admission stamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSzCl.jpg) are not [visas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjWCf.jpg).

Comment: Canadian citizens do not need most types of nonimmigrant US visas to travel to the US to enter on those statuses. What visa are you applying for? What form is asking you and is it specifically asking for previous "visas" or previous entries? As a Canadian citizen you would very likely have never gotten a US visa before, as you didn't need one.

Comment: I am going to do my postdoc in the US. Applying for a J1.

Comment: As a Canadian, you likely have never had a US visa, unless you've worked in the US.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must be referring to the ink stamps in your passport that you received at the border, which have a space for "class" and "until."  Immigration officers often leave those spaces blank.  Those stamps are not visas but admission stamps.  You should not list these on your visa application.

A US visa is a full-page sticker placed in the passport before you travel to the US.  These always show the type and expiration date.  (Several decades ago they were stamped into the passport with ink, and those visas could be indefinitely valid, but they were full-page stamps and they also always showed the visa type.)